# Computed field display based on user id

Tags: users, nodes, entities

I have content type name "applicant profile" which all the applicant need to fill up their details and information in this content type..the title for this content type is based on applicant name..
i want to make another content type name "pitch" which have computed field type..

My question..
Since "applicant profile" title is based on applicant name,how i want to display the name of node from "applicant profile" base on user id in computed field for "pitch" content type??
I prefer to retrive the data from "node" table in database..
Can someone help me on how to set the coding for computed field..thank you..